# Error implementing react-native-story-share

Tags: android, react-native, instagram, instagram-story

I'm trying to share imagens from my react native app which is running at v 0.61.5 to instagram stories. To do so I'm using react-native-story-share library at version ^0.4.0.

I have done the whole implementation of the library, which is showing me some erros. I thought at first that the errors where related to the implementation of the lib it self, but when I delete the implementations and execute react-native run-android it shows following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.snapchat.kit.sdk:creative:1.1.4.
```

If I dont delete the implementation process, following error appears:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/.../android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 11; O atributo "name" vinculado ao namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" j� foi especificado para o elemento "meta-data".
```

That may occur because I already use metadata name for facebook, when not using the suggested metadata from the lib, following error occurs:

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.snapchat.kit.sdk:creative:1.1.4]
```

Im dealing with these 3 erros but im clueless when dealing with it. I tried opening snapchat documentation, but couldnt find anything there related to this problem aswell. There is also nothing related to this kind of problem at the documentation of the lib